# Let $M$ be a symmetric and positive definite block matrix. Prove that the matrix $D$, an element of $M$ is symmetric and positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, block-matrices

> **Prove** that $D$ must also be positive definite matrix, given that $M$ is symmetric and positive definite matrix.

Consider the block matrix $$M=\begin{bmatrix}
A & B\\ 
C & D
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $A \in Mat_{n\times n}, \  B \in Mat_{n \times m} , \  C \in Mat_{m\times n}, \ D \in Mat_{m\times m}$.

D is invertible.

I have a notion that I have to use the Schur complement, but I have no Idea how. 
And I think I don't really get what the Schur complement really is.

I tried to write the Matrix as a multiplication of two matrices containing the Schur complement. but it did not get anywhere.

The other idea was that the I know that the diagonal entries of $D$ must be positive. but again this seems of no help.

Comment: Any principal submatrix of a positive definite matrix must be positive definite.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, but why is that true?

Comment: I was hoping that the term "principal submatrix" might jog your memory towards a result from you notes.  In any case see my answer below.

Comment: many thanks, no we've never looked towards block matrices in lectures....but that is so simple that I should have seen it myself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $M$ is positive semidefinite.  The for any non-zero $y \in \Bbb R^{n+m}$ we have $y^TMy > 0$. So, for any non-zero $x \in \Bbb R^m$, we can set $y = (0,x)$ to find that
$$
0 < y^TMy = \pmatrix{0&x^T}\pmatrix{A&B\\C&D} \pmatrix{0\\x} = x^TDx.
$$
So, $D$ is positive definite.