# Block symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Given is symmetric block matrices $M$ of the form
$$
M=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
A & B \\
B^{\top} & C
\end{array}\right)
$$
where $A$ is a constant, $B$ is $1 \times n$ vector and $C$ is a $n \times n$ symmetric matrix. Under which conditions on eigenvalues of $C$ is this matrix negative definite? Can I say if matrix C is negative definite, M will be negative definite too since A is a constant?

Comment: Notice, just to start, that in order for $M$ to be negative definite, the constant $A$ must be negative. $e_1^\top M e_1 = A$, after all.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3428318/let-m-be-a-symmetric-and-positive-definite-block-matrix-prove-that-the-matrix What about this one? Here we can only check D? @TedShifrin

Comment: Be careful with your logic. I'm saying that $M$ negative definite *implies* $A<0$, not vice-versa (the converse is false). In the case of the one you linked, *if* the big matrix $M$ is positive definite, *then* $D$ must be positive definite, not vice-versa.

Comment: Note: Consider the case $n=1$. Even if $A$ and $C$ are negative scalars, $M$ will often be indefinite. A simple example is this: $$\begin{bmatrix} -1&2\\2&-2\end{bmatrix}.$$ Then with $v=e_1+e_2$, we have $v^\top Mv = 1 > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

[Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) implies that $M \prec 0$ iff $A \prec 0$ and $C-B^TA^{-1}B\prec 0$. Equivalently, $$M \prec 0 \Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}A < 0\\  C\prec \frac{1}{A}B^TB\end{cases}.$$
Since $\frac{1}{A}B^TB$ is a rank-one matrix, It has one eigenvalue equal to $\frac{1}{A}BB^T$ and other eigenvalues equal to zero. Therefore, if $A < 0$ and eigenvalues of $C$ are less than $\frac{1}{A}BB^T$, then $M \prec 0$.

$\textbf{Edit:}$

This is only a sufficient condition. A necessary condition is $A <0$ and $C \prec 0$. That is, eigenvalues of $C$ should be negative. However, I do not know the necessary and sufficient condition in terms of the eigenvalues of Matrix $C$.

Comment: I think it would be worth mentioning that your last implication is only sufficient.

Comment: What would be necessary condition? @KBS

Comment: This is now completely muddled. Please edit it to make it correct. You start out with stating iff two times.

Comment: @Maica A necessary and sufficient condition is that $M$ is negative definite if and only if $A$ and $C-B^TA^{-1}B$ are negative definite. This is also equivalent to say that $C$ and $A-BC^{-1}B^T$ are negative definite.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be Hermitian with eigenvalues $\lambda_1\geq\cdots\geq \lambda_n$ and let
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix}A&c\\c^*&t\end{pmatrix},
$$
with eigenvalues $\beta_1\geq\cdots\geq\beta_n$. Then we have the interlacing inequalities $\beta_1\geq\lambda_1\geq\cdots\geq\beta_n\geq\lambda_n\geq\beta_{n+1}$.

Thus is if $B\succ 0$, then so is $A$. Conversely if $A\succ 0$, then it suffices that $\det B > 0$ (Sylvester’s criterion). But $$\det B = \det(A)(t -c^*A^{-1}c),$$ so it suffices that $t -c^*A^{-1}c> 0$. The negative definite case is treated by considering the negatives of $A$ and $B$. Also, you can move $A$ at the bottom right by a suitable permutation similarity.

**Edit**: we can expand a bit more on this. If we scale $t$ and $c$ by $\|c\|_2^{-2}$, then the last inequality can be lower bounded as so:
$$
t>c^*A^{-1}c\geq \min_{\|x\|_2=1}x^*A^{-1}x=\lambda_1^{-1}>0.
$$

Comment: I guess there is a typo here. I should be $\det B = \det(A)(t -c^*A^{-1}c)$, which in the end gives the Schur complement condition.

Comment: @KBS Yes, you’re correct!

Answer (score 1):

A necessary and sufficient condition is that $M$ is negative definite if and only if $A$ and $C-B^TA^{-1}B$ are negative definite. This is also equivalent to say that $C$ and $A-BC^{-1}B^T$ are negative definite. This follows from the Schur complement formula.

There is, in general, no condition on $C$ alone unless in some very particular cases.